# Combining two gene counts in one single plot using ggplot2?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

Display of two gene counts in the same graph along two different conditions. Normalized Counts for these genes were obtained from Deseq2 using plotcounts functions. To plot these two genes in the same plot with the same x-axis which has three conditions Ctrl,T1,T2 and different y-axis (based on counts). And one extra variable is the replicates PAT1,2,3,4,5 which i want to be distinguished by different shape and genes "x" and "y" with two different colors. I tried something like this from the link mentioned which did not really worked so far
geneX

```
genecounts <- plotCounts(dds, gene = paste(geneX), 
              intgroup = c("timepoint","patient"),returnData = TRUE)  


#               count timepoint patient  
# PAT1.ctrl 19.975535      ctrl    PAT1  
# PAT2.ctrl 15.095701      ctrl    PAT2  
# PAT3.ctrl 31.067328      ctrl    PAT3  
# PAT4.ctrl 23.507453      ctrl    PAT4  
# PAT5.ctrl 64.955803      ctrl    PAT5  
# PAT1.T1   25.087863        T1    PAT1  
# PAT2.T1   12.265661        T1    PAT2  
# PAT3.T1   21.514517        T1    PAT3  
# PAT4.T1   12.853989        T1    PAT4  
# PAT5.T1   29.887820        T1    PAT5  
# PAT1.T2   16.234911        T2    PAT1  
# PAT2.T2    7.620990        T2    PAT2  
# PAT3.T2   36.834481        T2    PAT3  
# PAT4.T2    7.085464        T2    PAT4  
# PAT5.T2   13.330165        T2    PAT5
```

second gene Y plotcounts

```
#            count  timepoint patient
PAT1.ctrl 156949.94      ctrl    PAT1
PAT2.ctrl 164856.70      ctrl    PAT2
PAT3.ctrl 258139.79      ctrl    PAT3
PAT4.ctrl 103669.21      ctrl    PAT4
PAT5.ctrl 434170.02      ctrl    PAT5
PAT1.T1   128839.83        T1    PAT1
PAT2.T1    98877.64        T1    PAT2
PAT3.T1   198419.57        T1    PAT3
PAT4.T1    97918.21        T1    PAT4
PAT5.T1   306861.69        T1    PAT5
PAT1.T2   124161.91        T2    PAT1
PAT2.T2    92150.86        T2    PAT2
PAT3.T2   265243.35        T2    PAT3
PAT4.T2    90364.91        T2    PAT4
PAT5.T2   399177.04        T2    PAT5
```

So far i used this code to generate individual ggplots

```
#ggplot(genecounts, aes(x = timepoint, y = count, color = patient)) + geom_beeswarm(cex =3)
```

Any help/suggestions would be highly appreciated

Comment: I am not seeing genes "x" and "y" in your example data?

Comment: I have updated the question with the data for both the genes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first step is to add a column for the gene name to each data frame, then combine them.

You could start with `geom_point`: I would use color for patients and shape for genes. You will want to use a log scale, since the counts differ by orders of magnitude. Assuming that your data frames are named `geneX` and `geneY`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

geneX %>% 
mutate(gene = "X") %>% 
bind_rows(mutate(geneY, gene = "Y")) %>% 
ggplot(aes(timepoint, count)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color = patient, shape = gene)) + 
  scale_y_log10()
```

[image]

You can try `geom-jitter` instead to avoid point overlap.

If you want to connect the points, you will need to group by both gene and patient, which is a little more work:

```
geneX %>% 
mutate(gene = "X") %>% 
bind_rows(mutate(geneY, gene = "Y")) %>% 
ggplot(aes(timepoint, count)) + 
  geom_line(aes(color = patient, group = interaction(patient, gene))) + 
  geom_point(aes(color = patient, shape = gene)) + 
  scale_y_log10()
```

[image]